# concat string and for iteration using jinja2

Tags: jinja2

I would like to create a variable name using a concatenation of a string and for iteration:

```
{% for iteration in my_array %}
   {% set my_var = 'my_string_' + loop.index0|string %}
   {{ my_var }}
{% endfor %}
```

in my python file with data:

```
templateVars={
    'my_string_0': 'test with 0',
    'my_string_1': 'test with 1'
}
outputText = template.render(templateVars)
```

but I don't get 'test with 0' I get 'my_string_0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'my_string_'` is just a string, not a variable. Since your "variable" names are just named with incremental numbers, you should make it a list instead:

```
outputText = template.render(my_array=['test with 0', 'test with 1'])
```

so you can iterate through the list in the template:

```
{% for item in my_array %}
   {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```